# Existe em português um equivalente a "freaking awesome"?

Tags: tradução

Vejo bastante o uso desse termo em inglês porém o mesmo não possui uma tradução. Existe um equivalente em português?

Comment: Vale usar palavrão?

Comment: @BellAppLab se estiver dentro do contexto não vejo problemas...

Answer (score 7):

De acordo com o Google Tradutor, ***"Freaking Awesome"*** significa ***"Muito Bom"***, o mesmo que ***"Very Good"***, mas é claro que sabemos que ***"Freaking Awesome"*** é uma coisa bem mais intensa que ***"Very Good"***, então ao meu ver, acho que uma não existe uma tradução equivalente a ***"Freaking Awesome"*** no Português...

Eu usaria ***"Impressionante"*** ou até mesmo ***"Foda"***, que é um termo vulgarmente utilizado aqui no Brasil para coisas que vão além do ***"Muito Bom"***.

Comment: Ou então ***"Brutal"***, em Portugal.

Answer (score 7):

Considerando que "freaking" é um substituto mais educado para "fucking", eu sugeriria **do cacete** (em comparação com *do caralho*, que, por algum motivo, é de mais baixo calão no português brasileiro).

Comment: Outra variante em Portugal é "do baril".

Comment: @user3397179 qual o significado dessa expressão exatamente?

Comment: @RodrigoBorth... significa "freaking awesome", claro?

Comment: @g4v3 acho que tens uma **boa** resposta se juntares os teus vários comentários. A pergunta não é limitada a português do Brasil... força! :)

Answer (score 3):

Existem algumas expressões que combinam, mas utilizam palavras de baixo calão.

As mais comuns são:
- Do caralho
- De fuder
- Bom pra caralho

Em porto alegre eles usam "a fuder": http://www.lpm.com.br/livros/Imagens/dicionario_de_porto_alegres.pdf